# Java Swing - Problem with inseting component(JTextArea) in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing

I want to add multiple new JTextArea in JTextPane at runtime on button click. For that i have set Box layout for my JTextPane and i add new component in that using mytextpane.add() method.
but it is getting resized and repositioned depending on layout and does not retain the original size of it which i had assigned. Also as i add more component to it, the inserted components are getting shrinked but i want a scrollbar to show up when i add more components to my JTextPane. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: public class TestPane extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form TestPane */
    public TestPane() {
        initComponents();

       
    }
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        jTextPane1.insertComponent(new JTextArea("hi i am madhvi"));

        jTextPane1.revalidate();

    }

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test

Comment: Hi  camickr , i have done exactly how you and its working fine. But the only thing i want now is to everytime i want to insert new component in new line . how do i accomplish that? and my jtextArea should take width same as my JtextPane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you add components to a JPanel, so I'm not sure why you are attempting to add them to a JTextPane. The basic code is:

```
panel.add( someComponent );
panel.revalidate();
```

However, if you really are trying to add them to a JTextPane then you should be using the insertComponent() method of JTextPane.

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether the JTextPane is the component you should be using for this purpose.
JTextPane is suited when you want add a multline text editing interface to your UI
(say embedding a markup editor). May be JScrollPane would better suit your needs.