# Java Swing - problem insert component in JTextPane

Tags: java, windows, swing, grouplayout

The below given program insert a new JTextArea on button click. Everytime new TextArea is inserted in new Line. The program is working fine on Linux machine but not on windows machine. On windows machine it is giving me BadLocationException . Can anyone please tell me the solution of this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class TestPane extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form TestPane */
StyledDocument doc = null;
public TestPane() {
    initComponents();
    doc = jTextPane1.getStyledDocument();
    //BoxLayout messageLayout = new BoxLayout(jScrollPane1,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
    //jTextPane1.setLayout(messageLayout);
}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextPane1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(164, 164, 164)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1,
                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 376, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                 286, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jTextPane1.insertComponent(new JTextArea("hi this is StackOverflow "));
    jTextPane1.revalidate();
    insertEmptyLable();
}


private void insertEmptyLable() {
    try {
        doc.insertString
                (jTextPane1.getText().length(), "\n",
                null);
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new TestPane().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really mean to do `insertComponent()` each time `actionPerformed()` gets called? I'd have expected something more like this:

```
private void insertMessage() {
    try {
        doc.insertString(jTextPane1.getText().length(),
           "Hi, this is StackOverflow.\n", null);
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Addendum: Comparing this with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294288/java-swing-problem-with-inseting-componentjtextarea-in-jtextpane) on the same topic, you should consider whether you want to insert *text* or a *text component* in the scroll pane. Also, NetBeans' GUI designer has matured considerably, but it doesn't lend itself well to short examples.